# Accessing Web.Config from a separate solution

Tags: dll, web-config, connection-string

I have two solutions, one is a class library and the other is a web application, and I want to get the connection string from the web.config file to the class library as I am developing a custom membership provider. I am using Framework 4.0 and MS Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the configuration settings for any library in the main web.config. It's easy!

Connection strings are especially easy. Just add your connection string to the `connectionstrings` section with the same name it has in the library's app.config, and you're done!

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Sitefinity" connectionString="your connection string"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

To add configuration settings, at the top of your web config, find the `applicationSettings` section, and add your section's info. Note: be sure to set your library's settings access modifier to "Public". You can do this in the Properties ui.

```
<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
  <section name="Your.Assembly" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Then, add the section under `applicationSettings`.

```
<applicationSettings>
<Your.Assembly>
  <setting name="TestSetting" serializeAs="String">
    <value>a test value</value>
  </setting>
</Your.Assembly>
</applicationSettings>
```