# Error using DLL from other project - ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 projects, 1 is a REST service the other is ASP.net website.  They each run independently.  But I want to re-use global functions form the REST service in my ASP.net project.  The issue is that the Global class is static and us setting vars using the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Property"];

What is a better way to handle this?

Edit: One thought I had was creating a generic XML file that the two projects could both share and read from instead of a web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just have your application call the REST service.

Second, if you are worried about the `AppSettings`, there is no reason you cannot include the same settings used by your service in the web config of your application. As long as you keep the names the same and include the right section, they will still work.

Third, why not extract the functions you want to share into their own library?

Comment: I want to avoid having the same settings in each web.config file when most of them will be identical.  Just trying to see if there is fast way to do this.  Thanks for the input

Comment: Well, you could use managed settings (create a "Settings" file in your REST project). These settings, while still stored in your config file, will be strongly typed, and also included at compile time. Because they are included at compile time, you only need to add them to the web config if they have changed.

Comment: That sounds promising, do you know a good resource on that explains how to do that?

Comment: See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893577/accessing-web-config-from-a-separate-solution/9951356#9951356 and also try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wabtadw6.aspx